# ORACLE SQL Query with Filter in all columns

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE = '%ABC%'
```

This query will search for a string in any column and return the result. But I want to get all rows which contain that string in any of the columns.

Is there any way to get the output after filtering in all the columns?

NOTE: I have a table which has 50 columns, so using a for loop and hitting the database 50 times (one for each column) is not time efficient.

Comment: Relational table has static number of columns. You do not need a loop to filter each column in separate query, just combine filters via `or` using a tool that generates a query:  programming language or your hands - it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

We can concat the strings of those columns and apply the condition on this entire string:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM yourtable
WHERE 
column1 || column2 || column3 
LIKE '%ABC%';
```

Of course, there are some possible edge cases that this would fetch rows where for example column1 has a string 'AB' and column2 a string 'CD' and such rows should not be selected. If this is the case, we will need to use `OR` instead.

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM yourtable
WHERE 
column1 LIKE '%ABC%' 
OR column2 LIKE '%ABC%'
OR column3 LIKE '%ABC%';
```

Or we can follow the first option and add some separator between the columns:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM yourtable
WHERE 
column1 || 'S' || 
column2 || 'S' ||
column3 
LIKE '%ABC%';
```

In my opinion, all these options are unpleasant. That's because pure SQL is not good in such things.

I recommend to do this in your application rather than as pure SQL query. Or you could at least find a complete string to search in the columns to avoid the `LIKE`. Then you could do this:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM yourtable
WHERE 
'yourString' IN (column1, column2, column3);
```